# how to get count in mysqli_fetch_object help me out

Tags: php, mysql

```
echo $getq2 = "SELECT publisher,COUNT(publisher) from (select publisher from wiley where $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM elsevier WHERE $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM sage WHERE $getq2_  UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM indianjournal WHERE $getq2_) as publisher Group by publisher order by publisher";

$getquery1 = $conn->query($getq2);
```

after the query fetching through

```
while($runrows =mysqli_fetch_object($getquery1))
   {
      print_r($getquery1);

      echo $pub=$runrows->publisher;
      //getting the publisher list
      echo $count=$runrows->count['publisher'];
      //not grtting the publisher count
 }
```

I'm getting the publisher, but not the count. How can I get the count?

Comment: try this $runrows->COUNT(publisher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your query you can get by like this

```
$runrows->COUNT(publisher);
```

or change the query into . like this set the alias name like this `COUNT(publisher) as count`

```
echo $getq2 = "SELECT publisher,COUNT(publisher) as count from (select publisher from wiley where $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM elsevier WHERE $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM sage WHERE $getq2_  UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM indianjournal WHERE $getq2_) as publisher Group by publisher order by publisher";
```

and get like this

```
 $runrows->count;
```

Comment: here after try to set alias name  and its easy to use . glad to help you . if my answers is useful mark it with green ticks its useful to future users @Gaurav

Comment: hey jyothi m newbie here so can u pls tell me where shud i need to click for green tick.

Comment: srry got it ..  :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $getq2 = "SELECT publisher,COUNT(publisher) as pub_count 
// provide a proper column aliasing so that you can refer it
```

and use it like:

```
echo $count = $runrows->pub_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Query like this `COUNT(publisher) As count` and you can

```
echo $count=$runrows->count;
```