# Not getting count From this query through mysqli_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysql

this is my query for count value and its count

```
echo $getq2 = "SELECT publisher,COUNT(publisher) from (select publisher from wiley where $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM elsevier WHERE $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM sage WHERE $getq2_  UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM indianjournal WHERE $getq2_) as publisher Group by publisher order by publisher";

$getquery1 = $conn->query($getq2); 
after the query fetching through

while($runrows =mysqli_fetch_object($getquery1))
   {
      print_r($getquery1);

      echo $pub=$runrows->publisher;
      //getting the publisher list
      echo $count=$runrows->count['publisher'];
      //not grtting the publisher count
 }
```

I'm getting the publisher, but not the count. How can I get the count?
result is getting properly

Comment: used the COUNT(publisher) as count and than echo $count=$runrows->count
outside the loop

Comment: similar question asked tomorrow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825441/how-to-get-count-in-mysqli-fetch-object-help-me-out/39825518#39825518

Comment: it was by mistake Abhishek gurjar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the query to like this.

```
echo $getq2 = "SELECT publisher,COUNT(publisher) as publisherCount from (select publisher from wiley where $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM elsevier WHERE $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM sage WHERE $getq2_  UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM indianjournal WHERE $getq2_) as publisher Group by publisher order by publisher";
```

and use `echo $pub=$runrows->publisherCount` to get publisher count

Answer (score 0):

echo $getq2 = "SELECT publisher,COUNT(publisher) as pub from (select publisher from wiley where $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM elsevier WHERE $getq2_ UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM sage WHERE $getq2_  UNION ALL SELECT publisher FROM indianjournal WHERE $getq2_) as publisher Group by publisher order by publisher";
 query shuld be like this and 
echo $pub=$runrows->pub